# Problems with layer labeling QGIS standalone C++ application

Tags: qgis, labeling, c++

```
    mypLayer->setCustomProperty("labeling", "pal");
    mypLayer->setCustomProperty("labeling/enabled", "True");
    mypLayer->setCustomProperty("labeling/fontFamily", "Cantarell");
    mypLayer->setCustomProperty("labeling/fontSize", "11");
    mypLayer->setCustomProperty("labeling/fieldName", "DRVAL1");
    mypLayer->setCustomProperty("labeling/placement", "1");
    mpMapCanvas->refresh();
```

Didn't work for me with QGIS 2.14. At the same time this code works fine at Python console in QGIS Desktop application on CentOS 7.5 x64.

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
layer.setCustomProperty("labeling", "pal")
layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/enabled", True)
layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/fontFamily", "Cantarell")
layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/fontSize", "11")
layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/fieldName", "DRVAL1")
layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/placement", "1")
iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried just using the boolean value for `True` excluding the quotes (i.e. `mypLayer->setCustomProperty("labeling/enabled", true);`?

Comment: yes, I've tried to use true, TRUE, "true", "TRUE" with the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was just a problem with layer. Code works as expected.